# regex: check if values exist in between commas

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl, I would like to determine if a given string is valid, the rule is to check if values exist between commas.

e.g. `abc,abc` is a valid case, but `abc,` or `abc,,abc` are not.

Comment: So no 2 commas in a row?

Comment: Just to be clear, is `abc,def` valid? And what about numbers, is `123,456` valid?

Comment: abc,def is valid. 123,456 is also valid. (as long as it is not a comma).   ,skfd is not.

Comment: Are spaces allowed around commas?

Comment: Actually I have just come up a workaround to test if the given string is valid under my rule.  I just compare the # of values separated by commas to the # of commas +1 in the string.  e.g. abc,abc is 2 = 1+1 but ,abc is 1 != 1+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m/^\s*,|,\s*,|,\s*$/
```

matches all invalid combinations, assuming whitespace does not count as "values".